# CSS Absolute Positioning of Images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to position several images in a  so they overlap with each other. I want to use absolute positioning, but for reason all of the images position themselves relative to the  and not to each other. If I use s instead of images this works. It appears that, unlike s, images do not position themselves relative to other images but only to a , is that correct?

**CSS**

```
#container2 {
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
}

.playingcard {
    width: 72px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=container2>   

    </div>

    <script src=script.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const imageArray = ['/images/back/purple_back.png', '/images/back/red_back.png', '/images/back/yellow_back.png' ];
const container2 = document.getElementById('container2');
console.log(container2);

for (i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
    const newImage = new Image();
    newImage.src = imageArray[i];
    newImage.className = 'playingcard';
    imgArray = container2.getElementsByTagName('img');
    console.log(imgArray.length);
    if (imgArray.length == 0) {
        container2.appendChild(newImage);
    } else {
        newImage.style.top = (i * 20) + 'px';
        imgArray[imgArray.length - 1].appendChild(newImage);
    }
}
```

Thanks
Denis

Comment: Have you tried changing the z-index?

Answer (score 0):

2 Observations

Your this code is never going to execute in a the for loop.

```
if (imgArray.length == 0) {
   container2.appendChild(newImage);
}
```

You are pushing image in imageArray, so your structure will be like this

```
<container2>
    <img src="src1">
      <img src="src2">
        <img src="src3">
        </img>
      </img>
    </img>
</container2>
```

Here even if you use position `absolute` to each image will be absolute to its parent. so you will see overlapping images.

Replace your else condition with this (Remove if also)

```
else {
        newImage.style.top = (i * 20) + 'px';
        container2.appendChild(newImage); // ADD THIS
        // imgArray[imgArray.length - 1].appendChild(newImage); // REMOVE THIS
    }
```

Your structure now will be as you are expecting. You can play around with the CSS to get a view you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that all `img` tags are nested within each other. Due to this, your `top` rule did not work. Example without condition `if`.

```js
const imageArray = ['https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2265897/d83bbab3-4bc4-42cc-8d62-a21b4c77ed72/s1200', 'https://64.img.avito.st/1280x960/4394790064.jpg', 'https://i.mycdn.me/i?r=AyH4iRPQ2q0otWIFepML2LxRUoA1zBVpY6nfGdB73g4vbw' ];
const container2 = document.getElementById('container2');
console.log(container2);

for (i=0; i<imageArray.length; i++) {
    const newImage = new Image();
    newImage.src = imageArray[i];
    newImage.className = 'playingcard';
    imgArray = container2.getElementsByTagName('img');
    console.log(imgArray.length);
    container2.appendChild(newImage);      
    newImage.style.top = (i * 20) + 'px';
}
```

```css
#container2 {
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
}

.playingcard {
    width: 72px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id=container2>   

    </div>

    <script src=script.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```